# App is blocked when opening from lock screen with face id

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, mdm, lockscreen

I have an app that forbids other apps from using the camera while my app is running, But when I turn it off and back on, my device has face id so my app is blocked just like when another app uses it. use camera. Here is my camera check code:

```
fun checkCameraAvailable(listener: ((isAvailable: Boolean) -> Unit)) {

    val manager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(object : AvailabilityCallback() {
        override fun onCameraAvailable(cameraId: String) {

            listener.invoke(true)
            super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId)
        }

        override fun onCameraUnavailable(cameraId: String) {

            listener.invoke(false)
            super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId)
        }
    }, handler)
}
```

Comment: Share your crash

Answer (score 1):

There is little information given in your original question but one of the valid issues could be that you are not stopping the camera preview properly when your app goes to the background after the device is locked.

You should [stop the preview and release the camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#TaskReleaseCamera) as soon as you don't need it anymore.

I'll quote the docs mentioned at that link:

> Once your application is done using the camera, it's time to clean up. In particular, you must release the Camera object, or you risk crashing other applications, including new instances of your own application.
>
> When should you stop the preview and release the camera? Well, having your preview surface destroyed is a pretty good hint that it’s time to stop the preview and release the camera, as shown in these methods from the Preview class.

```
override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
    mCamera?.stopPreview()
}

/**
 * When this function returns, mCamera will be null.
 */
private fun stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {
    mCamera?.apply {
        // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
        stopPreview()

        // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
        // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
        // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
        release()

        mCamera = null
    }
}
```

If you are using CameraX it should be bound to the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragment that is using it and thus released automatically.

[See an example here](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L334).